# Object not following curve properly

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to make this shape follow the curve using the curve modifier but for some reason it doesn't match the curve. Tried a few solutions i found online like setting the origin of object and curve to 0,0,0 and applying rotation and scale, but still can't find a way of fixing it

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is following the curve, but you're curving a curved object.  If you want it to follow the curve exactly, straighten out the base object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nathan says, the curve that has the *Curve* modifier is already curved, so even though it will be curved according to the *Curve Object*, it won't visually follow this second curve. To do so you need to switch to *Edit* mode and flatten the curve with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>:

[image]